# Chaining InputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

So i know that `InputStream` sees the data as raw data and `Reader` sees it as characters.

Buffered them will make things more efficient.

But how about chaining them like this:

```
InputStream in = new InputStream(...);
in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in);
r = new BufferedReader(r);
```

Is this right?

Comment: Given that `BufferedReader` will do buffering anyway, I doubt that using `BufferedInputStream` will help much...

Comment: You could carry on adding more and more buffers indefinitely. Until all available memory is exhausted.

Comment: Also, always specify the character encoding when creating a Reader. Otherwise it becomes environment-dependent.

Comment: `InputStream in = new InputStream;` won't compile

Comment: @LanceJava anyway you get the point, don't you?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15799469/3080094) explains when buffering is good and when buffering is just overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799469/3480200

With some opinion from others i conclude that:

It's not ok to use buffered inside another buffered in my case. It's useless.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 7**, Here is an example of application that simply read a file 4MB using `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` combined to `BufferedInputStream` and compare the performance of reading of bout techniques under Java 7.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainIO_Optimization {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            // ------ 1 ------ 
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("data/dictionnaire.txt")));
            isr = new InputStreamReader(bis);
            // ------ 2 ---------------
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/dictionnaire.txt")); 

            char[] buf = new char[10];


            // ****** Performance  *****

            // we get system time 
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // we simply read
            while( br.read(buf) != -1 );
            // print the time of execution  
            System.out.println("Time reading using BufferedReader with FileReader : "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) + " ms" );



            long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while( isr.read(buf) != -1 );
            System.out.println("Time reading using InputStreamReader with BufferedInputStream et FileInputStream : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2 + " ms" ));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{

            try {
                if(bis != null)
                    bis.close();
                if(isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                if(br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

### The resultats

> Time reading using BufferedReader with FileReader : 31 ms
>
> Time reading using InputStreamReader with BufferedInputStream et FileInputStream : 32 ms

As you can see the result is **1 ms** difference. `BufferedReader` is faster.

---

In **Java 8** , you better use `NIO` package rather than `IO`. So `FileChannels` will be more efficient.

Comment: actually my question is it ok to buffered (with BufferReader) what already buffered (BufferedInputStream)?

Comment: anyway, no need to buffer what it is already buffered .... you can adapt my code to check the performance of double buffering and single buffering :)